Showing $Ker(u-\alpha_1 Id)\circ (u-\alpha_2 Id) = Ker(u-\alpha_1 Id)\oplus Ker(u-\alpha_2 Id)$ for derivative operator.
Let $\partial$ denote the derivative operator on a space of infinitely differentiable functions.
I am trying to prove that
$$\ker \left(a(\partial - \alpha_1 \operatorname{id})\circ (\partial - \alpha_2 \operatorname{id})\right)= \ker(\partial -\alpha_1 \operatorname{id}) \oplus \ker(\partial - \alpha_2 \operatorname{id})$$
Here $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ are the roots of $\, aX^2+bX+c \,$ thus the first kernel is the same as the set of solutions of the linear ODE $\, ay''+by'+cy=0$.

Note: I've actually made all my calculations with $a=1$, so let's assume $a=1$ (because I suspect otherwise that there's an a missing in my direct sum.

So one way is pretty straightforward: if there is a function (in the space of infinitely differentiable functions) that writes uniquely as $y=y_{\alpha_1} +y_{\alpha_2}$ then, $(\partial-\alpha_2 Id)(y)=(\partial-\alpha_2 Id)(y_{\alpha_1})$
And $(\partial - \alpha_1 Id)\circ (\partial - \alpha_2 Id)(y)=(\partial - \alpha_2 Id)\circ (\partial - \alpha_1 Id)(y_{\alpha_1})=0$
Now, for the reverse part I found something that is seemingly incorrect, I'll write it nevertheless:
Let $y\in Ker (\partial - \alpha_1 Id)\circ (\partial - \alpha_2 Id)$. Then:

either $y\in Ker (\partial - \alpha_2 Id)$
either $y\notin Ker (\partial - \alpha_2 Id)$, in this case: $(\partial - \alpha_2 Id)(y) \neq 0$ and we have that $y\in Ker (\partial - \alpha_1 Id)$

This yields this nonsense implication: $Ker (\partial - \alpha_1 Id)\circ (\partial - \alpha_2 Id) \subseteq Ker (\partial - \alpha_1 Id) \bigcup Ker (\partial - \alpha_2 Id) $.
Maybe I should have reasoned in terms of "$Ker$ is non reduced to $\{0\}$" in this last part.
Any hint or help for this last part would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.
PS: in order to keep things simple, I am assuming here that $\alpha_1 \neq \alpha_2$. So that eigenspaces are of dimension one.

Maybe see it as a version of the kernel lemma? I.e. $\ker PQ (u) = \ker P(u) \oplus \ker Q(u)$ if they are coprime. https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemme_des_noyaux

As it is not really a good idea to answer in the comments, I write it down here.
You have an endomorphism $\quad \partial: C^\infty (\mathbb{R})\to C^\infty (\mathbb{R}) \quad$.
Now consider the following lemma (I have a reference in french only sorry Kernel lemma)

Lemma: Let $V$ be a vector space, $u \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ and $P,Q \in k [X]$ two coprime polynomials, then
$$\ker PQ(u) = \ker P(u) \oplus \ker Q(u)$$

The proof is fairly simple, you use Bézout theorem which gives you $U,V \in k[X]$ such that $PU + QV = 1$ and then You have your two projectors given by $\pi_P = QU(u)$ and $\pi_q = PV(u)$.
Now for you theorem, set $u = \partial$, $P= X-\alpha_1$ and $Q= X-\alpha_2$, since $\alpha_1 \neq \alpha_2$ they are coprime and
$$\begin{align*}
\ker \left((\partial - \alpha_1 \operatorname{id}) \circ (\partial - \alpha_2 \operatorname{id})\right)  &= \ker P(u) \circ Q(u) = \ker PQ(u)\\
&= \ker P(u) \oplus \ker Q(u)\\
&= \ker (\partial - \alpha_1 \operatorname{id}) \oplus \ker (\partial - \alpha_2 \operatorname{id})
\end{align*}$$
Of course if you have a double root, you have to consider the derivative polynomial and it’s a bit trickier. You could see it as a Jordan Block.
